# pandas extract all characters and digits after a pattern

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'd like to extract all digits and character regardless of pattern after "V". The issue is that I can't simply take all and including after " V" as some street names start with "V". I have tried the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['Seasame Street Apt 2 V2575', 'Happy Violet Street Apt 1 V2575B', 'Violet Street Apt 3 V25B75']})
df['Y'] = df['X'].str.extract('(V\/?\d+)')
```

What I'd like the final output to look like is as follows:

```
pd.DataFrame({'X': ['Seasame Street Apt 2 V2575', 'Happy Violet Street Apt 1 V2575B', 'Violet Street Apt 3 V25B75'],
                       'Y': ['V2575', 'V2575B', 'V25B75']})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that desired `V` part is always followed by a digit:

```
df["Y"] = df["X"].str.extract("(V\d.+)")
print(df)
```

Output

```
                                  X       Y
0        Seasame Street Apt 2 V2575   V2575
1  Happy Violet Street Apt 1 V2575B  V2575B
2        Violet Street Apt 3 V25B75  V25B75
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `np.where()` and `str.split(' ')`

```
df['Y'] = np.where((df['X'].str.split(' ').str[-1][0][0].lower() == 'v'), df['X'].str.split(' ').str[-1], '')
```

Comment: Thanks @david-erickson. I was thinking of approaching it from a split or position approach as well. this will be good to remember in the future.